# Skepticism in math

Tags: soft-question

Do any one have tips on not getting too skeptical while reading proofs. I am trying to self teach a math textbook but I keep on revising old proofs thinking that I am missing something.any suggestions.

Here is an example.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDIrx.jpg

I was stuck on this proof for over a month revising it as I found irrelevant information(and by irrelevant I mean information that no other step after it or before it depend on it and doesn’t add something to the proof)in paragraph 3 when author specified the the first j columns in first r-1 rows are row reduced. And I sometimes get stuck revising old material just thinking I might be missing something or I am just convincing myself that the proof is correct

Comment: I'd suggest you to add your own comments, remarks and computations to the proof while trying to understand it for the first time. This way, you will have a much easier time in the future when revising the proof. It may also help you not to be too sceptical of yourself. Seeing your own annotations in a proof is a reassuring sign that you have already spent a considerable amount of time to understand your proof, and may help you to just move on.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129075/discussion-on-question-by-abdrlrahman-skepticism-in-math).